# How to get refund amount from a given array of objects ? (Kind of complicated..)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say you were given an array of object data from database and you want to get REFUND result.
So you can give the amount of money when a user requests refund. Before we dive into the problem

```
- 'DEPOSIT' is the money that user deposit 

- 'POINT' is like an additional extra money/deposit that the business provide when the amount of deposit is over $30($30 deposit => 3 POINT is given,  $50 deposit => 10 POINT is given )

- 'POINT' is not refundable. 

- 'DEDUCTION' is the amount of money that user spent.

- THE RULE IS YOU NEED TO SUBTRACT DEDUCTION FROM DEPOSIT FIRST. AND WHEN DEPOSIT BECOMES 0 or NEGATIVE, WE SUBTRACT DEDUCTION FROM POINT (if exists..)  - you can realize what it means in the example 2
```

Let's say I got user 1's deposit history data by typing query.

```
const queryResult = [
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 50,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -5,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -5,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
];
```

In this case, the result must become

```
const result = {
    remained_deposit: 40,
    remained_point: 10,
    balance: 50 (remained_deposit + remained_point),
    refundable: 40(remained_deposit)
}


** explain: we have 50 deposit and subtract two deduction from deposit. 
(50 -5 -5 = 40)
```

So, when the user requests refund, the user must get refund $40 (not $50..)

**Let's see another case.**

```
const data2 = [
    {
        date: '2022-10-10 ',
        amount : 50,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -30,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : -25,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },

];
```

In this case, the result must become

```
const result2 = {
    remained_deposit: 10,
    remained_point: 5,
    balance: 15,
    refundable: 10
}

As we did above, we subtract deduction from deposit first.
50(deposit) - 30(deduction) = 20 (deposit)
20(deposit) - 25(deduction) = -5(deposit.. becomes negative)

In this case, we calculate with the POINT.
-5(deposit) + 10 (POINT) = 5(POINT)

if the user requests refund at this point, he/she can get nothing. 
Because remained balance which is POINT(5) is not refundable.

However since the user deposit 10 after the last deduction,
and if he/she requests refund at this point, remained_deposit 10 will be given to the user.
```

**Let's see one more confusing-looking case**

```
const data3 = [
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 50,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -40,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : 30,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : 3,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : -25,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },

];
```

In this case, the result must become

```
const result3 = {
    remained_deposit: 25,
    remained_point: 3,
    balance: 28,
    refundable: 25
}

**explanation

50(deposit) - 40(deduction) = 10(deposit)
10(deposit) - 25(deduction) = -15(deposit)

**even though deposit(30) comes first than deduction(-25), we subtract deduction from the very first deposit first. 

-15(deposit) + 10(point ) = -5(deposit)
-5(deposit) + 30(deposit) = 25(deposit)

What matters is that the first deposit needs to be whole subtracted first and then POINT is next.

When the user request refund in this case, he/she can get $25.
```

I hope the examples gave you some clues how you guys must calculate to get the refund.
If you are still confused, please let me know.
And if you guys can understand the problem, I would appreciate if you guys can advise me or give me a better clues, algorithms or solutions.

Thank you.

My JS Code Solution

```
let totalBalance = 0;
let totalRefund = 0;

// Get total balance 

for(let result of results){
    totalBalance += result.amount
}

console.log(totalBalance);



// Get total refund --it gets correct answer when it's case4(below), but it's wrong in case5

for(let result of results){
    totalRefund += result.amount
    // console.log(totalRefund);

    if(result.type === 'POINT'){
        totalRefund -= result.amount
    }

    if(totalRefund < 0){
            totalRefund = 0;
    }
}

// in case 5, the totalRefund supposed to be 15. But its result is 10...
```

case4

```
const results = [
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 50,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -45,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -10,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : 30,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 3,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
]


// totalRefund = 30 (correct)

50(deposit) - 45(deduction) = 5(deposit)
5(deposit) - 10(deduction) = -5(deposit)
-5(deposit) + 10(point) = 5(point)

the remain_deposit is 30 and remained point is = 8(5+3)
```

case5

```
const results = [
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 50,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -45,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -10,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : 30,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 3,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -10,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -10,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
]




// totalRefund = 10 (wrong)

50(deposit) - 45(deduction) = 5(deposit)
5(deposit) - 10(deduction) = -5(deposit)
-5(deposit) + 10(point) = 5(point)
5(point) - 10(deduction) = -5(deduction)
-5(deduction) + 30(deposit) = 25(deposit)
25(deposit) - 10(deduction) = **15(remained_deposit == refund)**
```

Googling and code by myself. But still get unwanted/unexpected result.
Some case, the code can get the refund correctly, but in some cases it doesn't.

Comment: same question from yesterday on a different acc?

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, however since the post has been deleted due to thumbs down, in this time I added my Javascript code to resolve the problems, rules and some more explanations.

Comment: as I said in your old post, I made a code that does almost everything you need except for that weird rule where you have to subtract all deductions from your 1st deposit first, even if there is another deposit

Comment: @ChrisG Good morning Chris( It's morning here). Thx for giving my post attention :) In my old post?!, I approved?! editing?!. If you don't mind, can you share the code even if it's not perfect?!

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, it does everything if executed in the order in which the operations are made in your array. Even if this does not answer your question completely I hope it helps with some of your doubts

```js
const data1 = [
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 50,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -5,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -5,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
];

const data2 = [
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 50,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -30,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -25,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },

];

const data3 = [
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 50,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : 10,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-10',
        amount : -40,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : 30,
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : 3,
        type: 'POINT',
    },
    {
        date: '2022-10-11',
        amount : -25,
        type: 'DEDUCTION',
    },

];

console.log(calculateRefund(data1))
console.log(calculateRefund(data2))
console.log(calculateRefund(data3))

function calculateRefund(arr){
    let remained_deposit = 0;//remaining deposit without the points
  let remained_point = 0;//remaining points
  let balance = 0;//total remaining
  let refundable = 0;//total refundable remaining
  let over = 0;//var to help calculate point substraction

  arr.forEach(function(element) {
    //when money is deposited
    if(element.type=='DEPOSIT'){
      refundable += element.amount;//refund
      balance += element.amount;//total
      remained_deposit += element.amount;//deposit
    }
    //when points are earned
    if(element.type=='POINT'){
      balance += element.amount;//total
      remained_point += element.amount;//points
    }
    //when deduction is made
    if(element.type=='DEDUCTION'){
        balance += element.amount;//total
      //condition if deduction is higher than remaining deposit
      if(remained_deposit < Math.abs(element.amount)){
        over = remained_deposit + remained_point + element.amount;//set over
        remained_point = over;//points after deduction
        remained_deposit = 0;//no remaining deposit left
        refundable = 0;//no refund left
      } else {
        //normal deduction
        remained_deposit += element.amount;//deposit
        refundable += element.amount;//refund
      }
    }
  });
  
  //create the return object
  let result = {
    remained_deposit: remained_deposit,
    remained_point: remained_point,
    balance: balance,
    refundable: refundable
  }
  //return result
  return result;
}
```